# CI doesn't return the view buffer

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration, codeigniter-2

My problem is when I load a view file, it sends it directly to the browser instead of returning it:

```
$output=$this->load->view('topic', $data, TRUE);
```

I’ve two controllers. Each controller extend another controller before it extend the `CI_Controller` such as :

```
topics_admin extends Backend(which extends CI_controller) 

topics extends Frontend (which extends CI_controller)
```

The first controller behaves as expected but the second one has the problem i’ve explained.
There are no major differences between the 2 Frontend & Backend controllers.

I’m using CI 2 and I haven’t touched the core classes.

What's wrong with it?

Comment: The problem is not in the code you have posted so far.  Maybe show us the context of your view load.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it .
There was undefined function in the view 
and it didn't show the error message because the function was in a tag attribute like that :

```
<a href="<?=member_url()?>/topics">Title</a>
```